# Deploy NextJs (ReactJS) on multiple CPU Cores

Tags: node.js, reactjs, multiprocessing, next.js, deploying

I'm deploying my NextJS web app on my Server (4 Core CPUs) through the command "npm run start". The Website with some heavy tasks done by Server (Server side rendering).

The the command "npm run start" establish a NodeJs WebServer to run my NextJS Website. Does the NodeJS Webserver use greater than 01 CPU to handle NextJS tasks ?

Should we use this run our website ?

Comment: Use [`pm2`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2) instead (with `-i max` option).